# How to populate in MongoDB without mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, lookup, populate

I'm working on a university project and I need to populate an array of objects with ObjectIds, but I can't use mongoose in my project. I have two collections - *subject* and *studyProgram*.

Example *studyProgram* document:

```json
{
  _id: ObjectId('111'),
  name: "Study program 1"
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
  language: "en",
  subjects: [
    {
      id: ObjectId('222'),
      optionality: "selective",
      credits: 8,
    },
    {
      id: ObjectId('333'),
      optionality: "selective",
      credits: 5
    },
  ],
}
```

Example *subject* documents:

```json
{
  _id: ObjectId('222'),
  name: "Subject A",
  description: "Subject A description.",
},
{
  _id: ObjectId('333'),
  name: "Subject B",
  description: "Subject B description.",
}
```

I need to populate objects in `subjects` array with appropriate documents from *subject* collection based on `id`. Basically what I'm looking for is this result:

```json
{
  _id: ObjectId('111'),
  name: "Study program 1"
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
  language: "en",
  subjects: [
    {
      
      _id: ObjectId('222'),
      name: "Subject A",
      description: "Subject A description.",
      optionality: "selective",
      credits: 8,
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId('333'),
      name: "Subject B",
      description: "Subject B description.",
      optionality: "selective",
      credits: 5
    },
  ],
}
```

So far I have tried using the following $lookup:

```json
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "subject",
    localField: "subjects.id",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "subjects",
  }
}
```

but this removes the `optionality` and `credits` attributes. Is there a way to achieve this without having to use mongoose? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

```js
db.studyProgram.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "subject",
      "localField": "subjects.id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "subjectDocs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "subjects": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$subjects",
          "as": "subject",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              {
                "$first": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$subjectDocs",
                    "as": "doc",
                    "cond": {"$eq": ["$$doc._id", "$$subject.id"]}
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "optionality": "$$subject.optionality",
                "credits": "$$subject.credits"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "subjectDocs": "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hdg_2EhZ7vI).

If `"$first"` is unavailable, tell your SysAdmin to upgrade MongoDB!  Until then, this will probably work.

```js
db.studyProgram.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "subject",
      "localField": "subjects.id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "subjectDocs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "subjects": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$subjects",
          "as": "subject",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$subjectDocs",
                      "as": "doc",
                      "cond": {"$eq": ["$$doc._id", "$$subject.id"]}
                    }
                  },
                  0
                ]
              },
              {
                "optionality": "$$subject.optionality",
                "credits": "$$subject.credits"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "subjectDocs": "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GSPoaXeWLlG).

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried it on mongoplayground and it works. However, when I use it in my project, I get an error that says: "Unrecognized expression '$first'". I believe it is because I'm on Mongo version 4.11.0 and $first is not available in this version. Is there any other operator I can use instead?

Comment: @MarekBalvín Yeah, I see `"$first"` is only available within `"$group"` with that version.  I updated the aggregation pipeline by using `"$arrayElemAt"`.  See updated answer.